# Regression (logistic) in R: Finding x value (predictor) for a particular y value (outcome)

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression, predict

I've fitted a logistic regression model that predicts the a binary outcome `vs` from `mpg` (`mtcars` dataset). The plot is shown below. How can I determine the `mpg` value for any particular `vs` value? For example, I'm interested in finding out what the `mpg` value is when the probability of `vs` is 0.50. Appreciate any help anyone can provide!

```
model <- glm(vs ~ mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, vs)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    stat_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: The predicted value for x is y_hat=e^(xb+c)/(1+e^(xb+c)). solve this for x.

Comment: If you want help interpreting the output of logistic regression, [UCLA](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm) has a great overview.

Comment: Why is this question getting down voted?

Comment: As written, it doesn't seem to be a question about how to implement an understood theory in R, but what the theory is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to calculate predicted values from your model is with the `predict()` function. Then you can use a numerical solver to find particular intercepts. For example

```
findInt <- function(model, value) {
    function(x) {
        predict(model, data.frame(mpg=x), type="response") - value
     }
}

uniroot(findInt(model, .5), range(mtcars$mpg))$root
# [1] 20.52229
```

Here `findInt` just takes the model and a particular target value and returns a function that `uniroot` can solve for 0 to find your solution.

Comment: That doesn't look right. Shouldn't the answer be more like 20.5?

Comment: Oh, I think you just need `type="response"` in `predict` so that you're returning probabilities instead of log(odds).

Comment: Ah, i didn't realize `stat_smooth ` was plotting the response by default. I've updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried to solve it by hand and I can't find a function in R that allows me to do it quickly. So I'm guessing the `findInt` function you've defined should be the simplest way to solve for x.

Comment: These were helpful. I wonder if there is any way to find such value without using an `lm` or `glm`. In other words, could we directly find the x value corresponding to a mathematical function defined in `R`?

Comment: @ydavidchen you can use functions like optim() or uniroot() with arbitrary functions.

Comment: how can you apply the solution when you have multiple regression? like when you have m<-glm(Y~ X1+X2 , data=data, family="binomial") where X1 is factor and X2 is continuous. and we are interested in finding X2 value.

Answer (score 7):

You can solve for `mpg` directly as follows:

```
mpg = (log(p/(1-p)) - coef(model)[1])/coef(model)[2]
```

Detailed explanation:

When you fit the regression model, the equation you are fitting is the following:

```
log(p/(1-p)) = a + b*mpg
```

Where `p` is the probability that `vs`=1, `a` is the intercept and `b` is the coefficient of `mpg`. From the model fit results (just type `model` or `summary(model)`) we see that a = -8.8331 and b = 0.4304. We want to find `mpg` when `p`=0.5. So, the equation we need to solve is:

```
log(0.5/(1-0.5)) = -8.331 + 0.4304*mpg
log(1) = 0 = -8.331 + 0.4303*mpg
```

Rearranging,

```
mpg = 8.8331/0.4304 = 20.523
```

In general, to solve for `mpg` for any value of `p`:

```
mpg = (log(p/(1-p)) + 8.8331)/0.4304
```

Or, to make it more easily reproducible:

```
mpg = (log(p/(1-p)) - coef(model)[1])/coef(model)[2]
```